# Flutter doctor on Windows10 is not recognizing the AndroidStudio plugins

Tags: android-studio, flutter, failed-installation

Both Flutter and Dart plugins are installed in AndroidStudio (v3.6) but flutter doctor does not seem to be recognizing them.

AndroidStudio is installed via JetBrains Toolbox

Flutter doctor is reporting:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at D:\Flutter\sdk
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (7 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\tradj\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-R, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\tradj\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Users\tradj\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\192.6241897\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Users\tradj\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\192.6241897
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling AndroidStudio. Plugins are configured in AndroidStudio.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Flutter doctor in android studio will only work properly after setting up the paths of their sdks in android settings for both: flutter & dart. 
Checkout **File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > dart & flutter** and set their paths there. It will start working after that.
This works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, as mentioned, both plugins have been configured in AndroidStudio. AndroidStudio is displaying the correct version strings for both Dart and Flutter under Languages & Frameworks

Comment: Have you set those paths in environment variable path?

Comment: Yup. It's very weird. I can actually build the default "example" flutter app in AS, and run it up in the emulator, but doctor is still saying the plugins are missing.

Comment: It seems because of caching. Though you can try flutter clean, invalid cache and restart. :)

Comment: I hope you got your answer. :)

Comment: Still can't get doctor to report the plugins. However, as this is not blocking on development I'm going to write it off as one of those things, no matter the OCD prickling :) Thank you for your suggestions